# how to set tabs into side menu pages in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this code

**app.componnents.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
 pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform){
     this.initializeApp();
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Page One', component: Page1 },
      { title: 'Page Two', component: Page2 }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs #tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
  tab3Root: any = ContactPage;

  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController ) {
  }
}
```

**page1.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.
  </p>

  <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" fixed>Fixed Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="tel" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4" placeholder="Tel Input"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

I tried to add `tabs` into `sidemenu` pages but it almost failed. `sidemenu` uses totally different routing. 
any idea how to add `tabs menu` to `side menu` pages?

I used `ion-footer` tag in `page1.html` but it doesn't work properly.

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: not yet. still when navigation to side menu pages wich are different from tab pages tab bar removing.

Comment: Did you check `conference app` of `ionic`.

Comment: Yes I've checked it now the same as mine code. tabs only appears in . pages that we set them in tabs.ts tabs.html

Answer (score 1):

Reza, 
I have done some work around on side menu combined with tabs

```
https://github.com/jvaranam/Ionic3-Sidemenu-tabs
```

Comment: Dear @jose-g-varanam, You have the tabs in sidemenu, this mean this two tabs are same pages that sidemenu refer. if tabs menu refer to 2 pages that are not in sidemenu so in tabs menu we could have side menu but in any pages that side menu refer we could not see tabsmenu. this is the main part of my question . how to solve this.